# Core Data fetchedresultscontroller question : what is "sections" for?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm trying to get to know Core Data (I'm a noob at iPhone development) and in order to do this I'm trying to get an object from the fetchedresultscontroller and NSlog it's name (a property of the object). I tried to do it like this:

```
NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[fetchedResultsController sections]];
Task *t = [ar objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", t.taskName);
```

However, the app crashed with this error: the app crashes with the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[_NSDefaultSectionInfo
>   taskName]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x3d1f670'

I have since learned that you need to use the fetched objects property for this, but then what is sections for? Thanks for any help, sorry if this is a supremely stupid question. I've looked over the documentation but still don't understand.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` can group your objects into sections based on a key you specify. So, for example, if your entity had a `category` property, you could group your objects by `category` and display them under a heading for that category.

Every `UITableView` (and every `NSFetchedResultsController`) contains at least one section, so even if you're not using this functionality, you'll still have to deal with sections. If you [check the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW18), you'll see that the objects in the `sections` property conform to the [`NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo) protocol, which has the `objects` property that contains the objects in that section.

There are two ways to get an actual object out of a `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:0];
Task *task = [sectionInfo.objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

The other, much simpler, and preferred way is to use the `objectAtIndexPath:` method.

```
Task *task = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

These two samples are equivalent. UIKit [adds some methods to `NSIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) to make working with table views and fetched results controllers easier. Also, notice that the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods all provide you with `NSIndexPath` objects, so you can generally just pass these to `objectAtIndexPath:` to get the correct object for that cell.

Apple also provides a [decent tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305) on using Core Data on iPhone. It will answer a lot of your questions. Unfortunately, it doesn't cover `NSFetchedResultsController` in depth.